# Codeigniter4: pictures with correct paths in html are not loading

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-4

I have simple codeigniter4 project setup from tutorial docs: https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/tutorial/static_pages.html

the problem is that browser isn't showing pictures even though the src paths are correct. As you can see below i tried using url helper, tried relative paths but nothing works. I even deleted .htacces file but still nothing. Important thing is that this is codeigniter issue since i tried this in my vanilla project and it works.

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('/public/imgs/glacier.jpg')?>" alt="glacier">
<img src="/public/imgs/orbs.jpg" alt="orbs">
```

My pictures are in public/imgs folder.
This is error from browser console:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8080/codeigniter4/index.php?debugbar”. home:6:1
```

I only begun using codeigniter4 so this is really upsetting to me. Its driving me crazy :(

PS.I hope i've provided all the info required, since this is my first question.
I'm looking forward to answers :)

Comment: Why do you have "public" in the path? If you have it setup correctly the path should be /imgs/glacier.jpg.

Comment: At first i tried putting pictures at /imgs but it didn't work either

Comment: How do you have your server setup? The public folder is the "Document_Root". One way to determine that is to do a var_dump ($_SERVER) and see what the DOCUMENT_ROOT entry is.

Comment: ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(17) "/opt/lampp/htdocs"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

base_url(); outputs the path you have add in your App.php file under config Folder
when you open App.php you will find

```
public $baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/'
```

change   this to your preference path
eg:
public  $baseURL ='http://your-domain-name/your-project-name/

Answer (score 0):

maybe it helps you try this

```
src="'<?php echo base_url() ?> '/public/imgs/glacier.jpg"
```

Comment: did you check what is base_url outputiing

Comment: output:http://localhost:8080 but my relative src isn't working either

Answer (score 0):

Ok i pasted this as a src and it works: http://localhost/codeigniter4/imgs/glacier.jpg

but still i dont undersand why relative paths dont work, and i would like to know what is a proper way to manage src links.

Comment: Please - view your HTML Source from your browser - Usually Right Mouse Click -> View Source. So you can see the actual generated HTML. That's the number one thing to do in cases like this... See what the links are. That will tell you a lot. It should be a habit to view your HTML Source to ensure all your HTML is correct.

Comment: this is what i found when looking at a source: `<img src="http://localhost:8080/public/imgs/glacier.jpg" alt="glacier">
<img src="/public/imgs/orbs.jpg" alt="orbs">`

Comment: I see what was problem now.Sorry for bothering you with such a stupid question. The problem was that i screwed up links completely because i didn't add the root of the project. Thanks man you was very helpfull :)

Comment: It happens to the best of us. But now you know a new trick to check things so all is good :)

Comment: One more note, I've edited .env file with this: app.baseURL = 'http://localhost/codeigniter4' so now base_url contains this link. Now i can do base_url("/imgs/img.jpg") Is this a correct way?Yeah thanks once again man ur awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i chip in hopefully i can help.

in CI4 i use base_url().

```
base_url('images/something.png')
```

Avoide using the bellow.

```
base_url('public/images/something.png')
```

if you still face a issue double check your base url

keep in mind CI4 is newly released and you may face issues that may make you pull your hair. However its coming up well.

avoid using relative

I hope this helps.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. The problem was i didn't set up my .etc file correctly so base_url pointed to localhost root. Now it's working fine :)